# POST variable containing a pound (sterling) sign breaks submission to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, post, encoding

I use some time tracking software on my Mac called 'Minco' and it has a feature whereby all times recorded by the software can be sent to a PHP script to be added to a MySQL database.  I have this working fine, using the POST method to send the data from the software to the script, which submits the POST variables to the database, i.e.:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name VALUES('','$_POST[title]', '$_POST[date]', '$_POST[start]', '$_POST[end]', '$_POST[minutes]', '$_POST[amount]', '$_POST[notes]', '$_POST[uid]', '$_POST[type]', '$_POST[hash]')";
```

I am experiencing an issue though when I set the software to include the 'amount' variable.  This variable contains a pound (Sterling) sign, and when included it breaks the submission of all other variables to the database, i.e. a new row is added, but all columns have nothing entered.

I am assuming that the issue is related to the encoding/decoding of the pound sign, but I am not sure how to troubleshoot this issue.  Could someone suggest how I could go about this?

Comment: use mysql(i)_real_escape_string($_POST)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Bobby Tables rides again!

Answer (score 2):

Please, use a column list and prepared statements.

If the destination column is not expecting an HTML character, then you should strip it before sending it.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_user', 'my_password', 'world');

/* check connection */
if (!$link) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO $tableName (col1, col2, col3, col4) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssss', $_POST[title], $_POST[date], $_POST[start], $_POST[end]);

/* execute prepared statement */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

printf("%d Row inserted.\n", mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt));

/* close statement and connection */
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);

/* close connection */
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: +1 for being the only answer so far to explicitly not use mysql_*

Answer (score 0):

you can handle it in different ways

- use `mysql(i)_real_escape_string($_POST[])`
- or

  $amount =  $_POST[amount]';

  $amount = str_replace ('YOUR POUND SIGN','',$amount) ;

and use `$amount` variable in your string

- you can also try this `'\$_POST[amount]\'`

Answer (score 0):

Few things to try. It's true that you can include $variables directly in a string when the string is enclosed by double quotes, but when you're inserting an array variable, you have to enclose *that* in curly braces:

```
$myvar = "{$_POST['myvar']}";
```

I personally would just concatenate your string so that you can use the mysql_real_escape_string() method to escape values going into MySQL. Something like the following:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $table_name 
        VALUES('',
               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["title"]) . "', 
               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["date"]) . "', 
               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["start"]) . "', 
               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["end"]) . "', 
               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["minutes"]) . "', 
               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["amount"]) . "', 
               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["notes"]) . "', 
               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["uid"]) . "', 
               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["type"]) . "', 
               '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["hash"]) . "')";
```

Comment: mysql_* is obsolete and deprecated in all but name.  Don't use it, use mysqli or pdo instead.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is using ISO-8859-1 encoding but your database is using UTF-8 encoding then you will try to send the pound sign as an 0xA3 byte which the database will reject as being an invalid UTF-8 sequence.

The reverse mistake of a page using UTF-8 encoding but the database using ISO-8859-1 encoding is harder to spot as the database will just think you are sending it a 0xC20xA3 byte sequence rather than a U+00A3 character.